# Tate conjecture and finiteness of Brauer group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

What is the exact relation between the Tate conjecture for divisors on $X$ and finiteness of the Brauer group of $X$? And what is the reference for these relations?

More precisely, let $X$ be a smooth proper variety over a finite field $k$, and $\ell\neq p=\mathrm{char}(k)$. Then one can formulate a number of conjectures about its cohomologies:

$(T_{\ell})$ The cycle class map $NS(X)\otimes \mathbf{Q}_\ell \to \mathrm{H}^2_{\mathrm{et}}(X_{\overline{k}}, \mathbf{Q}_\ell(1))^{G_{k}}$ is surjective;

$(T_{p})$ The cycle class map $NS(X)\otimes \mathbf{Q}_p \to \mathrm{H}^2_{\mathrm{crys}}(X/W(k))[1/p]^{\phi=p}$ is surjective;

$(B_\ell)$ the $\ell$-power torsion group $Br(X)[\ell^\infty]$ is finite;

$(B_p)$ the $p$-power torsion group $Br(X)[p^\infty]$ is finite;

$(B)$ the Brauer group $Br(X)$ is finite.

What is the precise relation between all these conjectures? Are they equivalent?

1. If $X$ is a surface, it was proven in [Milne's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971042?seq=1) that all these claims are indeed equivalent.
2. I believe that it is not hard to see that $(T_\ell)$ and $(B_\ell)$ are equivalent for a fixed $\ell$.
3. Morrow [showed](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ematthew.morrow/Morrow,%20M.,%20Variational%20Tate.pdf) that $(T_\ell)$ for a fixed $\ell$ is equivalent to all other $(T_{\ell'})$  and to $(T_p)$.

So basically the question is whether $T_p$ is equivalent to $B_p$ (or if there is an implication in one direction?) and whether $B_\ell$ (or $B_p$) is equivalent to $B$?

UPD: Actually, the argument in Milne's paper does not seem to use that $X$ is a surface to show that $(T_p)$ is equivalent to $(B_p)$. So the only real question is to show that any of these conjectures imply $(B)$. For this, Milne seems to use that there is an intersection pairing on the Neron-Severi group of $X$.

UPD2: Actually, using the methods from the proof of Theorem 4.3 in the [paper of Morrow](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ematthew.morrow/Morrow,%20M.,%20Variational%20Tate.pdf), one can show that finiteness of $Br(X)[\ell^\infty]$ implies finiteness of $Br(X)$ by reducing to the case of surfaces. But I would be still curious to see direct proof (or a reference).

Comment: [Here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2017-54-04/S0273-0979-2017-01588-1/S0273-0979-2017-01588-1.pdf) is a relevant expository article. Tate conjecture for divisors is equivalent to finiteness Brauer or Tate-Shafarevich groups (over finite fields). [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.10222.pdf) is a new paper with a new proof outlining some of these relations. Finally your post is same question as [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73017/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-finiteness-of-the-tate-shafarevich-group-an) one. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user127776 I think the first link gives a reference only in the case of surfaces. The second link also discusses only the case of surfaces. I don't have access to Tate's paper now, but I don't think that, even for surfaces, it was known/proven before Milne that finiteness of $Br(X)$ is equivalent to the Tate conjecture for $X$.

Answer (score 3):

This could be seen as an extended comment. Here is a way that they are related outside of surface case:

- $T(X,n)$ is the conjunction of the Tate’s conjecture for X in degree n together with Beilinson’s conjecture that rational and numerical equivalence on X agree with rational coefficients in codimension n.
- $L(X,n)$ is the Lichtenbaum conjecture, states that $H^i_W(X,Z(n))$ (The Weil-etale motivic cohomology) is finitely generated.
  Then according to Thomas Geisser's work [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0205337.pdf) $L(X,n)$ implies $T(X,n)$ and if $T(X,n)$ holds for all smooth projective varieties over finite fields and all $n$ then $L(X,n)$ is implied.

Thomas Geisser in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.5544.pdf), Proposition 5.1 proves that $L(X,n)$ is equivalent to Conjecture 3.4 for a fixed $n$, which is finiteness of the groups $H^i_{et}(X,\mathbb{Z}(n))$ for all $i$ except $2n, 2n+2$ (there is a typo in the link $2n+1$ should be $2n+2$.). For $i=2n$ it is being finitely generated and for $i=2n+2$  the condition is being cofinite.

Since $Br(X)=H^3(X, \mathbb{Z}(1))$, then finiteness of $Br(X)$ implies $L(X,1)$ and hence $T(X,1)$. Conversely you need all of $T(X,n)$ for all $n$ and $X$ to get finiteness of $Br(X)$.

Comment: The equivalence between L(X,n) and T(X,n) depends on Lemma 3.9 in [this paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bruno.kahn/preprints/cell-ASENS.pdf) (see proof of Th. 7.4 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0205337.pdf)). Corollary 3.8 of the same paper gives a refined version of this equivalence, using the fact that Tate's conjecture implies Beilinson's conjecture in the presence of a nilpotence hypothesis which is verified e.g. for abelian varieties.